# Probability of rolling 4 dice

Tags: probability, dice

What is the probability of rolling 4 dice and getting at least one 4 and at least one 2? Dice are 6 sided.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Setup:**

This is an example of a question where it is far easier to calculate the probability of the complementary event, in other words the probability that this *doesn't* happen.

If we didn't successfully get at least one $4$ and at least one $2$, then that means in the four throws of the dice, we didn't get any $4$'s or we didn't get any $2$'s, possibly both.

From here, you should probably use inclusion-exclusion over the events "didn't roll any $4$'s" and "didn't roll any $2$'s."  Remember that inclusion exclusion implies $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Finally, once we know the probability of not rolling any $4$'s or not rolling any $2$'s, to find the original probability we were interested in, subtract this away from $1$.

Comment: Formatting tip:  If you type `$\Pr(E)$`, you will obtain $\Pr(E)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don't see enough of a difference to warrant using one over the other.  Some people even prefer using $\Bbb P(E)$.  Personally, I like the look of the slightly slanted $Pr$ over the perfectly vertical $\Pr$